# Reentering an if loop after else condition is met Python3

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I have a csv file with gene start and end sites. I want to loop though the file, condensing overlapping regions of transcription. My data is formatted as a list of short lists (containing "chromosome number", "start site", "end site"). In my code, I'm reading in lists from the list and condensing them under a loop the specifies that they must be on the same chromosome, else exit the loop. after I exit the loop though, I was to be able take a new chromosome number as the base line and restart the loop using it. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: hello, please provide a minimal working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would be best suited to use a function in this case.  Your function can take a Chromosome number and a list as parameters.  It would then process the data depending on the particular information you pass to it.

```
def loop_it(chromosome_number, _list):
    condensed_list = []
    for item in _list:
        if item[0]  == chromosome_number:
            condensed_list.append(item)
        else:
            pass
    return condensed_list
```

Then you can define your list and pass it to the function along with the chromosome number you are hoping to find it on.  so say you have a list:

`data_list = [[7, "ATG", "GCG"],[2, "AGG", "GCG"]] #format ->["chromosome number", "start site", "end site"]`

Now, you can iterate the list over and over using different chromosome numbers.

`chrome7 = loop_it(7, data_list)` and `chrome2 = loop_it(2, data_list)`